# QGIS - Clipping vector error message

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

I'm trying to clip a vector by extent, the first vector layer clipped fine, I tried to repeat this on a second vector layer and I have the following error message:

> ERROR 1: Cannot find OGR field for Arrow array ogc_fid
> ERROR 1: WriteArrowBatch() failed
> ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed 
> translation of layer subsqid_4_1_15 (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
> Process returned error code 1

Comment: Which version of QGIS? And are you using `native:extractbyextent` or `gdal:clipvectorbyextent`?